# Call to helper function from blade template in outside controller results in 'class not found'

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-blade

I am doing a proof-of-concept/toy example to try and familiarize myself with the ins and outs of Laravel and I ended up running into an error that I wasn't expecting.

Within my blade template, I made a call to a helper function contained within the controller (controller was generated via `php artisan make:controller CBookController`). And the call from within the blade template was `{{isset($val->prep) ? CBookController::toDate($val->prep) : ''}}`. I got it working and all was dandy. I decided that I wanted to pull that helper function out of that controller so that I could use it elsewhere in the project.
NOTE: I could only call the code from within the view if I included the line:
`<?php use app\Http\Controllers\CBookController; ?>` within the blade template

Mind you, this all worked properly and didn't throw any errors.

So here is where it started to get funky.

I made the call `>php artisan make:controller Helper`

I refactored all of the references in the view to say `Helper` instead of `CBookController` i.e.
`{{isset($val->prep) ? CBookController::toDate($val->prep) : ''}}` --> `{{isset($val->prep) ? Helper::toDate($val->prep) : ''}}`

and

`<?php use app\Http\Controllers\CBookController; ?>` --> `<?php use app\Http\Controllers\Helper; ?>`

before I refactored everything, it all worked properly. But after said refactoring, things started to get all screwy.

Please note: I do realize that for a more advanced laravel user, making a "helper" controller doesn't make sense. Again, as a more novice user, I was just trying to make small incremental changes that would still work as expected.
I am not trying to figure out the proper way to use helper functions (at least at this junction), nor figure out anything else other than, why would creating a new controller and then referencing that controller within the view give me guff.

My intuition is telling me that the `make:controller` is doing more behind the scenes than I am aware of and that is what is causing the issue, but I do not know what to look for or where to look.

Any explanation on why this small change breaks the page would be helpful

I can confirm that both the CBookController.php and the Helper.php are in the same directory, so there shouldn't be a filepath issue with the `use` statement in the view.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CBookController extends Controller
{


    public function main()
    {

        $result = \DB::connection('database')
        ->table("docs")
        ->join("plans","docs.bn","=","plans.bn")
        ->select('docs.bn',
            "plans.a",
            'b as Status',
            'c as fee',
            'd as exec',
            'e as mail',
            'f as prep')
        ->where('id','=','19')
        ->where('b','=','N')
        ->get()
        ->toArray();



        return view('test.Control_Book_Test')->with('result',$result);
    }

    public static function toDate($strToConvert)
    {
        return date("m-d-Y",strtotime($strToConvert));

    }
}
```

this is the original controller (edited column fields for anonymity, I believe everything was kept consistent, but regardless, it did work before hand)

The new controller is as follows

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Helper extends Controller
{
    public static function toDate($strToConvert)
    {
        return date("m-d-Y",strtotime($strToConvert));

    }
}
```

and finally, here is the view (before refactoring)

```
<?php use app\Http\Controllers\CBookController; ?>
@section('content')
<div style = "overflow-x: scroll">
        <table class="table table-striped- table-bordered table-hover table-checkable" id="magicWand">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Col 1</th>
                    <th>Col 2</th>
                    <th>Col 3/th>
                    <th>Col 4</th>
                    <th>Col 5</th>
                    <th>Col 6</th>
                    <th>Col 7n</th>
                    <th>Col 8</th>
                    <th>Col 9</th>
                    <th>Col 10</th>
                    <th>Col 11</th>
                    <th>Col 12</th>
                    <th>Col 13</th>
                    <th>Col 14<br></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach($result as $k => $val)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{isset($val->bn) ? $val->bn : ''}}</td>
                    <td>{{isset($val->ShortPlanName) ? $val->ShortPlanName : ''}}</td>
                    <td>n/a</td>
                    <td>{{isset($val->Status) ? $val->Status : ''}}</td>
                    <td>{{isset($val->fee) ? "$".number_format($val->fee,2) : ''}}</td>
                    <td>{{isset($val->exec) ? CBookController::toDate($val->exec) : ''}}</td>
                    <td>{{isset($val->mail) ? CBookController::toDate($val->mail) : ''}}</td>
                    <td>{{isset($val->prep) ? CBookController::toDate($val->prep) : ''}}</td>
                    <td>n/a</td>
                    <td>n/a</td>
                    <td>n/a</td>
                    <td>n/a</td>
                    <td>n/a</td>
                    <td>n/a</td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>

        </table>
</div>
@endsection
```

For brevity's sake, there's no point in repasting the entire file with just some refactored names, but here are the lines that contain the refactored reference

`<?php use app\Http\Controllers\CBookController; ?>` (very first line)

`<td>{{isset($val->exec) ? CBookController::toDate($val->exec) : ''}}</td>` (within the @foreach)

`<td>{{isset($val->mail) ? CBookController::toDate($val->exec) : ''}}</td>` (within the @foreach)

`<td>{{isset($val->prep) ? CBookController::toDate($val->exec) : ''}}</td>` (within the @foreach)

I expected the page to work just fine, but I end up getting the an error page with the message "Class 'app\Http\Controllers\Helper' not found"

Comment: perhaps you should do composer dump-autoload

Comment: Just to make sure: `app\Http\Controllers\CBookController` was a typo or it's `app` in your controller? Because it should be `App`

Comment: that is not a typo. I am working within the confines of what someone else already created. I am aware that it should be App, but that's what I am working with. Good clarification, I did not catch that.

Comment: @blinkofaneye Doing the `composer dump-autoload` unfortunately did not rectify the situation. Could you give any intuition on why you thought that might help? 

@LeonardoPrado I forgot to tag you in the previous comment, and for whatever reason, I cannot edit it. But I wanted you to be aware that `app` was not a typo. The folder is spelled `app` not `App`, again, I am working within the confines of what I was given.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a custom facade, for your custom function.

- Create a folder in App/Http/Custom
- Create a class DateHelper
- Add Your Function to the class
- Use the custom facade in your view using the `@inject`

**usage**

```
 @inject('helper', 'App\http\DateHelper');
      {{ $helper->toDate('params') }};
```

Comment: I am trying to get some understanding of why creating a new controller and then referencing it in the exact same way fails. I will reiterate what I said
"I am not trying to figure out the proper way to use helper functions (at least at this junction), nor figure out anything else other than, why would creating a new controller and then referencing that controller within the view give me guff."

Comment: @ZJC if you really wanna use the controller method only then you can use it like this `app('App\Http\Controllers\CBookController')->toDate()`, App method works exactly like @inject, both are for service injection

Comment: It fails because, its dependencies are loaded correctly, that's why we have `@inject` and `app()` helper service containers.

Comment: apparently you aren't understanding the conceptual question I am asking. I have controller A and controller B. They both have a function c. Calling A->c works. but calling B->c does not. I am NOT trying to learn how to use function c. I can already use it. I am hoping someone can give me some intuition as to why A->c works and B->c doesn't. Why are they different?

Comment: @ZJC I did a `php artisan make:controller Helper`, added a simple method, called it in my blade using `@php use app\Http\Controllers\Helper; @endphp`, and it threw an error, `class not found`, but it did not throw any error when i **changed app to App** and used `@php use App\Http\Controllers\Helper; @endphp`.